# render a user image and account link in the menu.html.twig

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-theming

I want to display a user picture (avatar) and some more fields in the **menu.html.twig** template.

I know that we can display these fields in a user.html.twig template.

```
{{ content.user_picture }}
{{ user.getDisplayName() }}
{{ content.field_name_user[0] }}
```

and etc.

But I want to display these fields in the ***menu.html.twig*** template.

As I think. we can make a variable in preprocess_block () and print the desired value.
Or if there is no necessary variable in the template - do it in the preprocessor of this template!

Help please make a decision on this issue. And what code you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to write a pre-process and define a variable and insert the desired elements in it.

```
hook_preprocess_menu__menu_name(array &$variables) {
    $userDetails = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    /**
    fetch the desired elements and pass to $variables eg:
    **/
    $variables['userPictureUrl'] = $userDetails->user_picture->entity->url();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_preprocess_menu:

```
function YOURMODULE_preprocess_menu(&$variables)
{

    $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

    if($uid > 0)
    {
        // Load user
        $user = User::load($uid);
        $userName = $user->getUsername();

        // If user have a picture, add it to variable
        if(!$user->user_picture->isEmpty()){
            $pictureUri = $user->user_picture->entity->getFileUri();

            // Add style to picture
            $userPicture = [
                '#theme' => 'image_style',
                '#style_name' => 'profile_picture',
                '#uri' => $pictureUri,
            ];
        }

        // Set variables
        $variables['MYMODULE'] = [
            'profile_name' => $userName,
            'profile_picture' => $userPicture,
            'profile_id' => $userId
        ];
    }
}
```

End show in your menu.html.twig file:

```
{{ YOURMODULE.profile_name }}
{{ YOURMODULE.profile_picture }}
{{ YOURMODULE.profile_id }}
```